# c# switch loop, adding up total for each case

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I have 2 codes that I want to combine into 1 and am having a lot of trouble doing it. The code should ask for the group number then their donation amount and loop back until they press 0. Once they press 0 it should show the total for all groups. Here are the 2 different codes

code 1

```
using System;
public class TotalPurchase
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double donation;
        double total = 0;
        string inputString;
        const double QUIT = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of the contribution: ");
        inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        donation = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
        while(donation != QUIT)
        {
            total += donation;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter next donation amount, or " +
                QUIT + " to quit ");
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            donation = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
    }
}
```

code 2

```
using System;
namespace donate
{

class donate
{
    public static void Main()
    {


        begin:
        string group;
        int myint;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter group number (4, 5, or 6)");
        Console.WriteLine("(0 to quit): ");
        group = Console.ReadLine();
        myint = Int32.Parse(group);

            switch (myint)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                     double donation;

                     string inputString;

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of the contribution: ");
                    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                    donation = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
                    goto begin;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect grade number.", myint);
                    goto begin;
                }




        }       
    }
}
```

So basically I want to find the total for each group using the 2nd code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a school project of some description?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use goto like that. Just use another while loop like you did in the first code segement.

It would be much more concise to say:

```
if (myInt > 3 && myInt < 7) { ... }
```

instead of using that switch statement.

Basically your code for summing up the donation amount does the trick, so just stick that inside a similar loop that handles what the group number is. If you do this you're going to want to use a different input to signify the end of donations vs the end of input altogether. It would be confusing if the application said "Enter 0 to quit input", followed by "Enter 0 to quit donation input".

Answer (score 0):

You are very close with Code 2. If you put Code 2 inside while loop it works!

The only code I have written for you here is declared myint outside the while loop and initialised it to a non-zero value.

```
    double total = 0;
    int myint = -1;

    while (myint != 0)
    {
        string group;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter group number (4, 5, or 6)");
        Console.WriteLine("(0 to quit): ");
        group = Console.ReadLine();
        myint = Int32.Parse(group);

        switch (myint)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                double donation;
                string inputString;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of the contribution: ");
                inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                donation = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
                total += donation;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect grade number.", myint);
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
```